# Error while trying to run ng test: should create FAILED

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Error: Cannot combine @Input decorators with query decorators

My spec file (didn't do any changes):

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Component file (completely empty):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent  {

}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the `login.component.html` that might cause this?

Comment: @R.Richards html template is comlpletely empty but this error still occures